# XML/lxml Parsing first occurrence using something like [0] maybe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xpath, lxml

The code below returns all the "str1"'s but I only want the first "str1" for each one of these: CrntRgstns->BrnchOfLocs->BrnchOfLoc. As in just "13A MAIN ST" not also "8 WATER ST." **Is there some type of [0] that would accomplish this?** Thank you.

**Current Code:**

```
from lxml import etree

f = open(r'C:\Users\Andrew/Desktop/xml_file.xml')

tree = etree.parse(f)
for e in tree.xpath('.//CrntRgstns/following-sibling::BrnchOfLocs/BrnchOfLoc'):
     print(e.attrib['str1'])
```

**Current Output:**

```
13A MAIN ST
8 WATER ST
```

**Desired Output:**

```
13A MAIN ST
```

**xml for 1 individual:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<IAPDIndividualReport GenOn="2021-01-03">
<Indvls>
<Indvl>
<Info lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="Anthony" indvlPK="2762691" actvAGReg="Y" link="https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/individual/summary/2762691"/>
<OthrNms>
<OthrNm lastNm="BIAMONTE" firstNm="PAUL" midNm="F"/>
<OthrNm lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="A"/>
<OthrNm lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="Anthony"/>
</OthrNms>
<CrntEmps>
<CrntEmp orgNm="MERRILL LYNCH, PIERCE, FENNER &amp; SMITH INCORPORATED" orgPK="7691" str1="ONE BRYANT PARK" city="NEW YORK" state="NY" cntry="United States" postlCd="10036">
<CrntRgstns>
<CrntRgstn regAuth="NJ" regCat="RA" st="APPROVED" stDt="2019-11-25"/>
</CrntRgstns>
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc str1="13A MAIN ST" city="SPARTA" state="NJ" cntry="United States" postlCd="07871"/>
<BrnchOfLoc str1="8 WATER ST" city="EAGLE" state="CA" cntry="United States" postlCd="90232"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</CrntEmp>
</CrntEmps>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch first item, use `[1]` (*you were so close with 0!*).

For example: `tree.xpath('.//CrntRgstns/following-sibling::BrnchOfLocs/BrnchOfLoc[1]')`

**Try:**

```
from lxml import etree

f = open(r'C:\Users\Andrew/Desktop/xml_file.xml')

tree = etree.parse(f)
for e in tree.xpath('.//CrntRgstns/following-sibling::BrnchOfLocs/BrnchOfLoc[1]'):
     print(e.attrib['str1'])
```

**Output:**

```
13A MAIN ST
```